# what does Math_class.sqr_func(x) represent

Tags: java

I was searching for a code in google. I got a code where Math_class.sqr_func(x) is written, I am unable to understand what this syntax means.

the urtl of the site is http://deepakjbhat.blogspot.in/2011_11_01_archive.html

Comment: It's just a function call.

Comment: which type of function you want to say , is it a method defined inside math class or a method defined by a programmer himself ?.

Comment: It is inside `Math_class`

Comment: I am new at java and my understanding is that to access a method in math class we use Math.sqrt() and there is no function defined for computing square of any number,than how we can use Math_class.sqr_func(x).

Comment: `Math` and `Math_class` are 2 different classes. `Math_class` is a class which is defined in the code that you linked to. Inside that class there is a function `sqr_func`. That program is not using java's `Math`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I didn't seen the method there now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

It's calling the static method `sqr_func` of the class `Math_class` (defined near the bottom of that page), with the argument `x`.

---

Note that the code you're looking at is frankly a really bad example of several things--most egregiously, naming conventions and coding style. That code would be much easier to understand if it simply used the standard, built-in `Math` class that Java already defines.

If another class to hold other methods is really required, it should be named something unambiguous (`Math_class` is absolutely terrible, because it verbally describes an unrelated object), and the methods should be named consistently (e.g. a method to square a value might be `MyMath.sqr`).

Comment: but what I know is that Math class is represented by Math not by Math_class.Is it a substitute of using Math class or what? .I am unable to understand it very clearly.

Comment: @user3078082 Yes, `Math` is a built-in class. For some reason, the code you're looking at defines its own class, called `Math_class`, with several methods. It's a perfect example of why you should use built-in classes and methods whenever possible: the alternative is all this needless confusion.